# Working locally and remotely at the same time with git

Tags: git, git-remote

I cloned a git repository from a git server.

I want First to create a new branch locally (in my local code). and then I want to make smoe changes on the code and then make somme local commit.

And then I want to commit the new local branch and the local commits to the git server.

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want First to create a new branch locally (in my local code)

- *git checkout -b your-new-branch*

> And then I want to make some changes on the code and then make somme
>   local commit.

- *git add .* (if you want to include all your changes in the commit)

Or

- *git add each-file-separately*

  *git commit -m "Your commit message"*

> And then I want to commit the new local branch and the local commits
>   to the git server

- *git push -u origin your-branch*

Also, these are all super basic git commands  and I strongly recommend reading the [Pro Git Book](http://git-scm.com/book) to understand how it works.

Comment: does this will create a my new branch in the git server too?

Comment: Yes, it will force the creation of your branch on your remote if it doesn't exist already

Comment: I can not see the branch in the history. graphical history(rabbit cvs) and console history